# Why are UI components always private in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm building Xamarin.Forms application.

My View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.Mobile.Views.MainView">
  <Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="TheFrame" />
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Then In App.cs I want to access `TheFrame`. Like this:

```
MainView mainWindow = new MainView ();
someFunction(mainWindow.TheFrame);
```

But! This is how auto-generated MainView.cs looks like:

```
public partial class MainView : ContentPage {

    private Frame MainFrame;

    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(MainView));
        MainFrame = this.FindByName<Frame>("MainFrame");
    }
}
```

**WHY?! How can I access `TheFrame` in App.cs?**

Comment: directly accessing a UI element from another class is generally a sign of a poor design.  If you really need to do this you can add a public property or method that provides the necessary access to the private element on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only be able to access the `Frame` from the code-behind using the `x:Name` property. Why do you need to access it from `App.cs`?

You could declare the `Frame` in `App.cs` and then add it to your page, which would allow it to be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: I need to pass `Frame` to my navigation class, which will handle navigation in the application.

Comment: @Sara Still confused on why you need that specific `Frame` for navigation. Are you trying to use the `Frame` on multiple pages or are you trying to navigate somewhere when they click the `Frame`? Or something else?